# Views 3 | How to programatically unset or add new value to a view's footer / header display?

Tags: 7, views

I have added 1 view display into my view's footer via "`Global: View area | The view to insert into this area.`" and a regular "`Global: Text area`".

So my view has 2 footer displays, one being another view display and the other a normal text area.

Now I want to unset/hide either one of the footer display based on a condition, perhaps via [hook_views_pre_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7)

I was expecting to find documentation on something like:

```
$view->display['MY_VIEW_DISPLAY_ID']->handler->handlers['footer']['FOOTER_DISPLAY_ID']->unset_display();
```

But obviously that is not the way to go. Is it possible to accomplish that via [hook_views_pre_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) or any other means? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The snap code below has been tested only on D7. In case this code does not work on D6, check out the comments on this [post here](http://drupal.org/node/749452).

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME' && $display_id == 'DISPLAY_ID') {

    // To find out the DISPLAY_NAME, FIELD_NAME and FIELD_VALUE use the devel module function
    // below to print them out.
    // Replacing 'footer' by 'header' works the same way.
    dpm($view->display_handler->options['footer']['DISPLAY_NAME']['FIELD_NAME']);

    $view->set_item_option($display_id, 'footer', 'DISPLAY_NAME', 'FIELD_NAME', 'FIELD_VALUE');

    // In this case scenario you needed to unset the footer display.
    // For the embedded view display you do like this:
    $view->set_item_option($display_id, 'footer', 'DISPLAY_NAME', 'view_to_insert', '');
    // For the normal text area display you do like this:
    $view->set_item_option($display_id, 'footer', 'DISPLAY_NAME', 'content', '');
  }
}
```

---

Due to comments, to determine what views name and display came to this function, make next (of course, "devel" module should be enabled)

```
    function MYMODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
      dsm($view->name);
      dsm($display_id);
      if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME' && $display_id == 'DISPLAY_ID') {
...
      }
    }
```

And update views page.

Comment: The snap code you've posted initially did not work but the link you posted along with it led me to the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

I have updated your answer.

Comment: To find out the `DISPLAY_NAME`, you can use `dpm($view->display_handler->get_option('footer'));`.

Comment: Make sure you are implementing hook_views_pre_view() --- this code only seems to work there, and not in other hooks like hook_views_pre_render().

Answer (score 2):

Views 3 example of adding some text to existing header programatically:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  $header_item = $view->get_item('default', 'header', 'text');
  $view->set_item_option('default', 'header', 'text', 'content', 'MY TEXT' . $header_item['content']);
}
```

Here is another example using `hook_views_pre_view`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view') {
    // Unset: Global: Text area
    $view->display_handler->set_option('empty', NULL);

    /* Programatically update the 'No results behavior' by inserting another view. */

    // Example 1
    $options = array(
        'id' => 'view',
        'table' => 'views',
        'field' => 'view',
        'empty' => TRUE,
        'view_to_insert' => 'new_view:page',
    );
    $view->display_handler->set_option('empty', array('view' => $options));

    // Example 2
    $view->set_item_option($display_id, 'empty', 'view', 'id', 'view');
    $view->set_item_option($display_id, 'empty', 'view', 'table', 'views');
    $view->set_item_option($display_id, 'empty', 'view', 'field', 'view');
    $view->set_item_option($display_id, 'empty', 'view', 'empty', TRUE);
    $view->set_item_option($display_id, 'empty', 'view', 'view_to_insert', 'new_view:page');
  }
}
```